# Can we set up PHP 7.x and Python 3.x in docker together?

Tags: python-3.x, docker, nginx, docker-compose, php-7.1

I am new to docker. I am trying to build docker containers with PHP 7.1, Python 3.5 which will communicate with common database server which indeed another container.

I want to know if this approach is possible and if yes how can it achieved? Or else what will be valid approach?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I advise you to use docker-compose with 3 services (Pyhton 3.5, PHP 7.1 and your DB) <del>and link them together. You can find more details on the "links" statement on this page: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links
By linking them you can reach all containers more efficiently.</del>
and you can create a docker network and connect your containers to it for isolates it. And reach them by their name, It's more secure and it's a good practice.

I hope that will help you.

Comment: There's no need for `links` - the key is deprecated and links are not required to enable services to communicate - by default, any service can reach any other service at that service’s name

Comment: That's true, but however you can create a docker network and connect your containers to it for isolates it. It's more secure and it's a good practice.

Comment: Compose creates a new network when you do a `compose up` and is by default isolated anyway so there's no need to create a network ahead of time

Comment: Thanks everyone. I will give it a try and will get back to you.